# "KeyError: rdflib.term.BNode" Error appeared when executing SPARQL query

Tags: python, sparql, ontology, rdflib

I'm trying to retrieve all intersection members for a specific class from a .owl ontology using SPARQL. I executed the following SPARQL query :

```
        PREFIX rdfs:<http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
        prefix owl:   <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
        select ?class ?i ?uri ?label where {
           ?class owl:equivalentClass/
           owl:intersectionOf/
           rdf:rest*/rdf:first ?i.
           ?uri rdfs:label ?label.         
           FILTER (?uri IN (<http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/AGRO_00000002>) )
        }
```

When executed it, I got an error :

```
"KeyError: rdflib.term.BNode('510')"
```

I'm using Python , Pycharm framework. For executing the SPARQL, I used both rdflib and owlready2. Can you please help me solve the error mentioned above?

Comment: Unfortunatly your post does not contain a question. What exactly is your point? Do you need a solution? General advise?

Comment: I need help to solve the error I got resulted from executing the SPARQL query mentioned above.

Comment: what is your query supposed to do with the labels? I mean, they are obviously unrelated to what you get in the intersection as the variable name `?i` is indeed not `?uri` - thus, the query would return a cartesian of all found intersection members with all labels in the ontology

Comment: also, the question would be which ontology (if possible to share or link to) and which rdflib version is used. Also the Python error stack trace is missing nor can we see the code you're using

Comment: hi @UninformedUser , the query suppose to retrieve all intersection members at the class "http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/AGRO_00000002>". rdflib version is 6.1.1. I'm targeting agro ontology which can be accessed through this link : http://agroportal.lirmm.fr/ontologies/AGRO